# Trying to pull changes from master repo into local branch and receiving fatal error (bitbucket, sourcetree, vscode). What am I doing wrong?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

New user to VS Code and Bitbucket and trying to pull changes from master into a local branch where I am working on the final stages of my dev work. I tried pulling/fetching these changes and received the following error:

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false --no-optional-locks fetch --no-tags origin
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false --no-optional-locks pull origin master
From https://bitbucket.org/blah_blah_blah_company_name/dbt
 * branch              master     -> FETCH_HEAD
fatal: Not possible to fast-forward, aborting.
Completed with errors, see above.
```

I'm not sure why I am receiving this issue but I am stuck. No other devs (2 of us) have seen this issue before.

Any ideas why this might be occurring?

Comment: *Completed with errors, see above.* What are the errors? What happens if you run `git pull` on the command line?

Comment: `git pull` is tricky and the VSCode gui just gets in the way. Instead, try saying `git switch my branch; git fetch; git merge origin/master` at the command line. (With your actual branch name of course.)

Comment: It doesn't give me any more info on the errors. AAAAND git merge origin/master while I was in my local branch worked. Thank you!

Comment: The formatting of the question seems to be a bit messed up. Can you clean up the question's formatting, so that it's clear what is the command being executed, and what is the actual response or error message, it's hard to tell.

Comment: I'm going to bet that if you say `git config pull.ff`, the reply will be `only`. If so, that's the cause of the issue. (If not, we're no closer to a solution and I lose my bet, but hey, that's life.)